# Type must implement the inherited abstract method TextToSpeech.OnInitListener.onInit(int)

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

Trying to become a bit more experienced, I follow the advice: code, code, then code some more. I am, however, completely new to OOP, Java and Android.

I found this on-line coding example: [Build a speak and repeat app](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-build-a-speak-and-repeat-app/).

The code:

```
    // extend the opening class declaration and implement the OnInitListener interface for TTS functionality
public class RepeatActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnInitListener
```

... produces this error in Eclipse Indigo:

> The type RepeatActivity must implement the inherited abstract method TextToSpeech.OnInitListener.onInit(int)

Does this have something to do with:

```
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
```

I have no idea how to solve this. Please advise. It is difficult to ask concrete questions about a subject one knows practically nothing about.

Cheers,

Pieter

Comment: Then perhaps the first place to go would be a tutorial on the subject?

Comment: The first place to go: that sounds like some sort of absolute truth :-). Like: this or that is the BEST operating system. There are millions of places to go if one doesn't know where to start.

Comment: As if I would be the kind of person not to already have tens of books on the topic :-).

Comment: If you already own more than ten books on Java, why haven't you read enough of at least one of them to have covered interfaces? If you know - by your own admission - practically nothing about a subject, the very first thing you should do is **read about it**. That should be obvious to anybody. This question is absolutely trivial if you know what interfaces are and how they're used, and this site really isn't here to replace reading about things for yourself or using Google.

Comment: People have different ways of learning things. I can learn Mandarin Chinese and Arabic on my own without other people because I have a built-in strategy for tackling the difficulties of learning human spoken languages. In the case of programming I learn by making mistakes. It is nice when one is allowed to learn in a way that makes sense. Making mistakes is a wonderful opportunity to learn. Punishing people for learning things their way is illogical somehow :-). Is it socially acceptable in your culture to impose your ways onto other people? That is not very open-minded, is it?

Answer (score 3):

Implement all the methods in your interfaces which are declared with your class..onInit() method may be there in **OnInitListener**. you must implement it in your class.

Add a method in your RepeatActivity  as follows.

```
public void onInit (int status){

      //what you want to do just after the completion of the TextToSpeech engine initialization
      }
```

Comment: Thank you for simply answering the question, which is what this is all about, without all those irrelevant judgements and suppositions about my intellectual and mental capabilities :-). This site is recommended in certain books for beginning Android programmers, by the way.

Comment: well  . . dude . but do consider reading core java thoruoghly. .this suggestion is for your own betterment

Comment: Why do you call a complete stranger "dude"? :-). No one said that this "dude" doesn't want to read. Reading isn't some kind of magical thing that makes everything clear, you know. I suspect many of you are autistic (which makes you great programmers).

Answer (score 3):

Normally, when your class implements your interface, it has to redefine all the methods in the interface. This is why it is called an interface:)

Comment: What I read is that an interface is like a collection of all possible "behaviours" of an object. That knowledge however does not logically provide for the insight that all methods need to be redefined. So reading books or tutorials doesn't always make human contact superfluous :-).

Comment: @user1447082 it's a description of behaviors just like the menu in a restaurant, can you eat the plates from the menu or do you have someone do (implement) them? but with a menu at least you know what you can order and this is exactly what an interface is :)

Answer (score 1):

You are saying that your class implements an interface, but your class doesn't contain all of the methods that said interface includes.

In simple terms, an interface is a contract that guarantees a class can perform specific functions, without saying **how** they go about doing them.

Comment: None of my books explain this like you do right now, so human interaction remains vital :-).